# Adding drop down menu to a template via CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I downloaded a template for a website but it just has a basic menu, I need to add a dropdown.

Not sure what code you need, so let me know if I need to post more.

Here is the coding for the menu, I added a div class of "nav" based on a tutorial.  So if I should do something entirely different let me know

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html"><span>About us</span></a></li>
<li><a href="2014chefs.html"><span>2014 Chefs</span></a></li>
<li><a href="mission.html"><span>Fund the Mission</span></a></li>
<li><a href="sponsors.html"><span>Sponsors</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="2014sponsors.html"><span>2014Sponsors</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="family.html"><span>Ambassador Family</span></a></li>
<li><a href="photos.html"><span>Photos</span></a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul></div>
</div>
```

Then this is the CSS coding, I figured most of it would be copied to my .nav so it has the same properties.

```css
.menu { padding:0; margin:0; width:949px; height:58px;       background:url(images/menu_bg.gif) top no-repeat;}
.menu ul { float:right; padding:0; margin:7px 30px 0 0; list-style:none; border:0;}
.menu ul li { float:left; margin:0; padding:0;}
.menu ul li a { float:left; margin:0 1px 0 0; padding:15px 0; color:#c8c8c8; font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none;}
.menu ul li a span { padding:15px; margin:0; background:none;}
.menu ul li a:hover { color:#60b6ff; background:url(images/r_menu2.gif) no-repeat right;}
.menu ul li a:hover span { color:#60b6ff; background:url(images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left;}
.menu ul li a.active { color:#60b6ff; background:url(images/r_menu.gif) no-repeat right;}
.menu ul li a.active span { color:#60b6ff; background:url(images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left;}

.nav ul ul{
display: none;}
.nav ul li: hover> ul{
display: block;}
.nav ul li{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
float:left; 
padding:0;
margin:0px;; 
list-style:none; 
border:0;}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;}
.nav ul li a { float:left; margin:0 1px 0 0; padding:15px 0; display:block; color:#c8c8c8; font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none;}
.nav ul li a span { padding:15px; margin:0; background:none;}
.nav ul li a:hover { color:#60b6ff; background:url(images/r_menu2.gif) no-repeat right;}
.nav ul li a:hover span { color:#60b6ff; background:url(images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left;}
.nav ul li a.active { color:#60b6ff; background:url(images/r_menu.gif) no-repeat right;}
.nav ul li a.active span { color:#60b6ff; background:url(images/l_menu.gif) no-repeat left;}
```

Comment: how are you adding the "active" class to your html?

Comment: The template doesn't have the active class, and it works fine.

Comment: Anyone able to help?